# What is the meaning of the phrase "разгульный образ жизни"?

Tags: перевод, значения, фраза

I've heard the phrase during the conversation of two teenagers. One was saying to the other, "Я веду разгульный образ жизни. Не знаю плохо это или хорошо."

What does that mean?

Comment: philandering, it's basically philandering I guess )

Answer (score 5):

Разгульный образ жизни can be translated into English as *a dissolute or rakish way of life* but it is less negative than  that. It is perhaps "easy" or sometimes even "wild" behaviour of a person who devotes his life to all kinds of  non-stop entertainment, eating out, drinking,parties,dancing, etc.

Answer (score 4):

It means something like `rackety life`.

> Я веду разгульный образ жизни.
>
> *I live a rackety life.*

Answer (score 1):

To me this means the person likes to go to wild parties, abuses all kinds of substances, is promiscuous, does not hold a steady job, have a business, or attend school, and generally does not go out of his or her way to be a contributing member of society. If you asked me to make up a sentence with it, the first thing that comes to mind is something along the lines of

`Суд лишил её родительских прав, так как она вела разгульный образ жизни.`

The court took away her parental rights as she lived a *I am having a hard time coming up with a concise, fairly common, well understood, and accurate adjective, I do not want to use "rackety" because it is not as common in English as "разгульный" in Russian but you get the idea* life.

The word гулять literally means to walk around for pleasure without a purpose, but can also mean to party in a wild manner. разгульный comes from the same root as гулять.

Comment: First, it is simply to walk.
Next, it is to walk with somebody.
Then they walk with somebody with romantic purposes.
Finally the word gains quite a connotation when used with the proposition "с". :-[

Answer (score 0):

the word "разгул" is mostly coincide by meaning with the word revelry.
So "разгульный образ жизни" is a style of life when revelry is present most to compare to other activities.

Answer (score 0):

In soviet times officials would use this term to describe a life style of drinking and partying. Conversely ordinary people would use this phrase as a joke parodying the officials. Most likely the teenagers were joking too